# How to listen to NodeJS https socket close event

Tags: node.js, sockets, https

I have the following code

```
var https = require("https");
var fs = require("fs");

var server = https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
}, function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(req.url);
});
server.listen(8765, "0.0.0.0", function() {
    console.log("listening");
});
server.on("connection", function(socket) {
    console.log("socket connected", socket.remotePort);
    socket.on("data", function() {
        console.log("socket data");
    });
    socket.on("close", function() {
        console.log("socket closed");
    });
    socket.setTimeout(3000);
    setInterval(function() {
        console.log("socket destroyed: ", socket.destroyed);
    }, 500);
});
```

When I make a request to the app, the "socket connected PORT" logs to console, but neither "socket data" nor "socket closed" ever logs. To make sure my event listeners aren't ignored, I set up a polling on `socket.destroyed` but it always logs `false`, no matter how much I wait.

I've made the request using chrome, safari, firefox, curl, but every one of my request gives the same result. I also did a Wireshark analysis and the client does indeed send a FIN packet and the server responds to it with its own FIN packet.

My question is, how can I get notified when the https socket closes? Is this socket some kind of proxy object made by the cypher to create clear text stream?

**Update**

The socket that NodeJS uses does close, as the `server.connections` changes as expected and if I call `server.close(callback)`, the callback does get executed and the process terminates gracefully.

Comment: The [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_connection) states: `the socket will not emit readable events because of how the protocol parser attaches to the socket.` May this be a hint to you? You could take a look at the socket.io implementation since this framework needs to keep track about open sockets also.

Answer (score 0):

From node documentation

#### socket.setTimeout(timeout[, callback])

*"When an idle timeout is triggered the socket will receive a 'timeout' event but the connection will not be severed. The user must manually end() or destroy() the socket."*

This probably means that it will not dispatch `close` event because the connection is not really terminated for it.

Try also to listen to `end` event instead of `close`.

#### Untested code

```
server.on("connection", function(socket) {
    socket.setEncoding('UTF-8');
    console.log("socket connected", socket.remotePort);
    socket.on("data", function() {
        console.log("socket data");
    });
    socket.on("end", function() {
        console.log("socket closed");
    });
    socket.setTimeout(3000, function(){
      socket.end();
    });
    setInterval(function() {
        console.log("socket destroyed: ", socket.destroyed);
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: I've tried to listen to end event, but gives nothing. The timeout callback works though, but that isn't really a close event. I tried to debug the net.js that comes with NodeJS, looked for the increment and decrement of the server.connections counter as that works. The result is pretty stunning, as the socket that gets emitted after the connections++ is different from the socket that emits the close event in connections--. Maybe this is a NodeJS bug?